# Unable to import android libraries

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

in my project after moving it from one pc to another via usb I started getting errors in every file on almost every line, but the app can still be built and run on an emulator.

From what I can tell android studio is having trouble finding the support-v7 library to import all the files

This is from my main activity:

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

And the error message I'm getting is:

> Unresolved reference: widget

This is my project level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

You can also see from this image [image: MainActiviy.kt file] that the intelli sens is throwing all kinds of errors, but if I run the it will launch and work perfectly in the emulator or on my device.

And this is from running gradle sync:

[image: Gradle build messages]

What I have tried so far:

- Re synced gradle by changing the app version code
- Build -> clean project
- Build -> rebuild project
- File -> invalidate cache / restart
- File -> sync project with gradle files

Comment: Why do you have 2 `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in your app gradle file? Please remove one and check again.

Comment: Tried it, same problem

Comment: import your project. Don't open from recent projects and open projects.

Comment: Thank you @Naveen, that solved my problem. If you want, you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Below steps.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to File - > New -> Import Project
3. Browse to the project location.
4. rebuild your project.

That's it.